# Sobolev embedding theorems on manifolds

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, manifolds, embeddings

I had asked the following question on math.stackexchange but did not get any response:

> I'm looking for a reference which states the Sobolev embedding theorems on Riemann manifolds for **fractional** Sobolev spaces.

The references I know either don't deal with fractional spaces, or don't deal with manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of Riemannian manifolds, Hebey wrote a book about it.
The main takeaway for Sobolev embeddings(not Morrey):
If M is compact, everything is quite fine and works as usually. If M is only complete, the situation is a bit different (depends on curvature).
For the general case, I unfortunately don't have a reference.